# Access 2016 query runtime

Tags: sql, ms-access, runtime, ms-access-2016

I am trying to find out the amount of IP's that correspond with each big category (big_cat). In order to do this I need to JOIN 3 tables.

I have the following 3 tables:

```
Large categories:
small_cat | big_cat

final_parsed_userlogs_access_longuri:
ip | uri

all_categories_from_all_unique_uri: 
uri | small_cat
```

And the following SQL query in Access 2016:

```
SELECT COUNT(Final_parsed_userlogs_access_longuri.ip), Large_categories.big_cat
FROM (All_categories_from_all_unique_uri INNER JOIN Final_parsed_userlogs_access_longuri ON All_categories_from_all_unique_uri.uri = Final_parsed_userlogs_access_longuri.uri) INNER JOIN Large_categories ON All_categories_from_all_unique_uri.small_cat = Large_categories.small_cat
GROUP BY Large_categories.big_cat;
```

The tables are 2.2 million, 4.4 million and 1.1 million lines long (in previously mentioned order). Obviously this will take quite some time to run, but I have been running this query for 1,5 hours now and it's still not finished.

**Is there a way to make this query run faster? I indexed all fields already.** If this is not possible; Is there a way to get a general sense of how long this query will take (through some equation or something)?

Comment: As a start use the builtin tools in MS-Access - `Database Tools | Analyze Performance` - you can probably add relationships between the key join fields, but the analyzer should tell you that

Comment: I did not know about that function, thanks! It made 2 suggestions which I used so let's see how long it takes now :)

Comment: It did not work, I left it on for about 8 hours and it still wasn't finished. Do you maybe have any other ideas?

Comment: Download SQL Server Express and import your data into it. It can handle bigger data sets much more efficiently than MS-Access. Otherwise I would pre-process the tables so the lookup tables are linked by AutoNumber ID fields instead of the text keys.

Comment: Thanks I will try that! :)

Comment: Damn I need windows 8 or higher for SQL Server Express but I have Windows 7 on this pc. I knew I should've upgraded sooner.. Do you know of a similar program that I can use for this that works on Windows 7? Because I don't really have time to make a big backup and install Windows 8 right now unfortunately :(

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=42299 v 2014